# Laravel Eloquent appending a non-relation ship data with the result

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8, eloquent-relationship

I have this model file:-

```
    namespace App;
    
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    
    class Observation extends Model
    {
        protected $fillable = ['observation', 'recommendation', 'priority', 'report_asset_id'];
        protected $appends = ['facility'];
    
        public function attachments()
        {
            return $this->hasMany('App\ObservationAttachment');
        }
    
        public function report_facility()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo('App\ReportFacility');
        }
    
        public function getFacilityAttribute()
        {
            return $this->report_facility()->facility;
        }
  
}
```

And this is my query code:-

```
$observations = Observation::orderBy('created_at','desc')
       ->with('attachments')->get(); 

       return response()->json($observations);
```

I am trying to append getFacilityAttribute to be included in result array .

I tried to use the protected $append model array but got error :-

> Call to undefined method
> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::facility()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line is incorrect:

```php
return $this->report_facility()->facility
```

You are starting a query, calling the `report_facility` as a function (`report_facility()`),  returns a query builder object, on which the `facility` function is unknown.

You should do:

```php
return $this->report_facility->facility
```

In this case, eloquent will give you the ReportFacility model, from which you can retrieve the facility property or relation.

It's similar to:

```php
return $this->report_facility()->first()->facility
```

Comment: Also, good to be sure with `return optional($this->report_facility)->facility;`.